# How can I execute a JavaScript function on the first page load?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there is a way to execute a JavaScript function once only on the first ever page load and then not execute on any subsequent reloads.

Is there a way I can go about doing this?

Comment: It depends on how you define "first page load", but yes, typically this is handled via cookies or `localStorage`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The code below will execute once the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event fires. The statement checks [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) the *onetime function* has **NOT** been executed before by making use of a flag (`hasCodeRunBefore`), which is then stored in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
        /** Your code here. **/
        localStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If the user clears their browsers' [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) by any means, then the function will run again because the flag (`hasCodeRunBefore`) will have been removed.

### Good news...

Using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) *can* be tedious because of operators and long winded function names. I created a basic [module](https://github.com/Script47/.js/blob/master/src/local_storage.js) to simplify this, so the above code would be replaced with:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (!ls.exists('has_code_run_before')) {
        /** Your code here... **/
        ls.set.single('has_code_run_before', true);

        /** or... you can use a callback. **/
        ls.set.single('has_code_run_before', true, function () {
           /** Your code here... **/ 
        });
    }
};
```

### **Update #1**

Per [@PatrickRoberts comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867229/how-can-i-execute-a-javascript-function-on-the-first-page-load/31867239#comment87917325_31867239), you can use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to see if a variable key exists in localStorage, so

```
if (localStorage.getItem('hasCodeRunBefore') === null)
```

becomes

```
if (!('hasCodeRunBefore' in localStorage))
```

and is less verbose and a lot cleaner.

**Secondly**, you can set values as you would an object (`localStorage.hasCodeRunBefore = true`) though it will be stored as a string, not as boolean (or whatever data type your value is).

Comment: Regarding the "good news" section, the specification does allow a `Storage` object to be used like a plain object with the caveat that all values are strings, for example you can check for existence with `'hasCodeRunBefore' in localStorage` and set it with `localStorage.hasCodeRunBefore = true`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ah, right, did not that you could use `in` for this. Thanks for that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for the edit, I was going to add the parenthesis but wasn't sure if they were needed. I did test in console with some dummy data and it seemed to work without the parenthesis (unless I did it wrong?). Out of curiosity, could you show an example where it would fail without the parenthesis or is the parenthesis there for safety?

Comment: `!'foo' in {}` vs. `!('foo' in {})`

Answer (score 3):

All JavaScript must execute every time a page loads. If the script is on the page, it will execute.

The *logic* that is executed within the JavaScript included on the page may execute in a different manner depending on the page state, input provided, and any other signals it receives, be it from the server or the client.

If you're using a server side language, you might choose to render a script conditionally, such as the first time a user logs in.

If you need to include the javascript irrespective of context, then you need to listen to other signals.

The simple modern solution is to make use of [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). `localStorage` can be used to store custom string values on custom key values for any given domain.

The code to make use of this would look like:

```
if (localStorage['...my key here...'] === '...my expected value here...') {
    // The page has been visited before
} else {
    // The page has not been visited before
    // OR
    // The user or script has cleared the localStorage value
}
localStorage['...my key here...'] = '...my expected value here...';
```

That's all well and good if you just need things to work on the client alone. Sometimes you might need the server to know whether or not the page has been visited before.

The (less)simple solution is to use [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie):

```
if (/(?:^|;\s*)...my key here...=...my expected value here...(?:;|$)/.test(document.cookie)) {
    // the page has been visited before
} else {
    // The page has not been visited before
    // OR
    // The user or script has cleared the cookie
}
document.cookie = '...my key here...=...my expected value here...';
```

If you need to defer the execution until the page has finished loading, then simply include the script in an `onload` callback, either by assigning the event to the window:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // do stuff when the page has loaded
    //this will override any other scripts that may have been assigned to .onload
};
```

or by binding the event handler to the window:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // do stuff when the page has loaded
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function toBeExecutedOnFirstLoad(){
  // ...
}
if(localStorage.getItem('first') === null){
  toBeExecutedOnFirstLoad();
  localStorage.setItem('first','nope!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what *first page load* means to you. It's subjective.

If you want the function to fire once the DOM has been parsed, but only the HTML and no other external resources, bind it to the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
```

Otherwise, if you want to wait for external resources to be loaded and then fire the event, you should bind it to the `window` object's `load` event like so:

```
window.addEventListener('load', fn);
```

Here are some links from the Mozilla Developer Network that explain the what I just said in more detail:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, you have simply included ways to fire code when the page loads or when the DOM loads, the OP wants to be able to fire the code only once.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368528/was-i-wrong-to-flag-this-as-naa)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing something similar, the difference in my case was, I wanted to run a code whenever a new instance was being created I needed a certain code to execute, and then later for the rest of the reloads that code should not execute.
For that similar to localStorage solutions above use session storage instead:

```
fun_RunOnlyOnFirstPageLoad(){}
if(!$window.sessionStorage.getItem(hasRunBefore)){
   fun_RunOnlyOnFirstPageLoad();
   $window.sessionStorage.setItem(hasRunBefore, true);
}
```

using the window.sessionStorage instead stores the value only for that session.
this way once the tab is closed (session is over, that value is wiped out) and on every new instantiation, the code is executed.