# Laravel include a js file in blade one-time-only after used has logged in

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder how I can include a one-time-only js file in blade once the user has logged in.

When the user logs in and gets redirected to a page I now want to include a new js file in my blade file that only should be available for this page and then doesn't show up again when the logged in user enters a new page, like a flash message

Does Laravel have any special way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `auth` blade directive to automatically insert a specifc script tag:

```
@section('scripts')
@auth()
<script src="{{ asset('js/file.js') }}"></script>
@endauth
@endsection
```

Comment: Yes, but this will include the script on each page if the user is authenticated. I only want to include the script once for 1 request right after log in

Comment: You can always set a flash session, it wouldn't be included again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use push stack if you are using laravel.In your blade you can add it push like this

```
@push('scripts')
    <script >
@if(Auth::user())
//your script here
@endif
</script>
@endpush
```

in your main master blade you can add

```
@stack('scripts')
```

so laravel will automatically append to your source

Comment: Yes, but this will include the script on each page if the user is authenticated. I only want to include the script once for 1 request right after log in

Comment: @Kiow.than you can set boolean once he logged in true so next time you can with isFirstTime

Comment: How should I set a boolean?  I only need the file once after login.  Eg:

User logs in > gets redirected to account page and JS file is included. User hits refresh, and reloads the account page > the js file isnt included anymore

Answer (score 0):

In `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` 
after

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

try adding:

```
@if (!Auth::guest())

    @yield('secure_template_scripts')

@endif
```

And then in your templates blade file add the following:

```
@section('secure_template_scripts')

    <script src="/pathTo/yourFile.js" ></script>

@endsection
```

If you want this is done just a single file you can do the following instead:

```
@if (!Auth::guest())

    <script src="/pathTo/yourFile.js" ></script>

@endif
```

Comment: Yes, but this will include the script on each page if the user is authenticated. I only want to include the script once for 1 request right after log in

Comment: Add the call to `@section('secure_template_scripts')` to the blade that is shown right after the user logs in.

Comment: But this will still load the file all the time as long as the user is logged in? I only need to load the file once after login Eg:
User logs in > gets redirected to account page and JS file is included. User hits refresh, and reloads the account page > the js file isnt included anymore

Comment: The question is not then of the laravel system but you need a conditional like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867229/execute-a-javascript-function-on-first-page-load